# Backup query add AG status

Tags: sql-server

I've inherited a query that reports "all" backups in a SSMS registered servers group.

I'd like to add a column of which AG the db instance is in and if it's primary.

I've tried adding a nested `SELECT` into the sys.databases section to extract the msdb.. into a column e.g (`SELECT role_desc FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states States as Role`)

But the result is 30 rows instead of 400+

What am I doing wrong?

```
Select  DB_NAME(database_id),
    Name as [Logical Name],
    Physical_Name as [Physycal Name],
    (size *8)/1024 as [Size in MB]
FROM sys.master_files
Where  database_id > 4

SELECT SUBSTRING(s.name,1,50) AS 'DATABASE Name',
    s.recovery_model_desc AS 'Recovery',
    s.state_desc AS 'Status',
    b.backup_start_date AS 'Full',
    b.is_copy_only,
    c.backup_start_date AS 'Diff',
    d.backup_start_date AS 'Log',
    b.user_name
FROM master.sys.databases s
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset b
  ON s.name = b.database_name
  AND b.backup_start_date =
  (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date)as 'Full'
   FROM msdb..backupset
   WHERE database_name = b.database_name
   AND type = 'D') -- full database backups only, not log backups
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset c
  ON s.name = c.database_name
  AND c.backup_start_date =
  (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date)'Diff'
   FROM msdb..backupset
   WHERE database_name = c.database_name
   AND type = 'I')
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset d
  ON s.name = d.database_name
  AND d.backup_start_date =
  (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date)'Log'
   FROM msdb..backupset
   WHERE database_name = d.database_name
   AND type = 'L')
WHERE s.name <> 'tempdb'
ORDER BY s.name;
```

Comment: I don't see `dm_hadr_availability_group_states` anywhere in your query?

Answer (score 1):

Will this work? I tried to keep as much as code for your question. The column names format is inconsistent.

```
;with replicaInfo (serverName, databaseName, replicaRole) AS
(
SELECT 
  ar.replica_server_name AS ag_replica_server, 
  db_name(dr_state.database_id) AS database_Name,
  ag_replica_role = 
  CASE
    WHEN ar_state.role_desc IS NULL 
    THEN N'DISCONNECTED'
    ELSE ar_state.role_desc
  END
FROM (
  ( sys.availability_groups AS ag 
    JOIN sys.availability_replicas AS ar 
      ON ag.group_id = ar.group_id )
    JOIN sys.availability_group_listeners AS agl
      ON ag.group_id=agl.group_id
    JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS ar_state 
      ON ar.replica_id = ar_state.replica_id)
    JOIN sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states AS dr_state 
      ON ag.group_id = dr_state.group_id
    AND dr_state.replica_id = ar_state.replica_id
)

SELECT 
  @@servername AS 'ServerName',
  databaseRole =
  CASE
  WHEN ri.replicaRole IS NULL
  THEN N'Database not in AG'
  ELSE ri.replicaRole
  END,
  SUBSTRING(s.name,1,50) AS 'DATABASE Name',
    s.recovery_model_desc AS 'Recovery',
    s.state_desc AS 'Status',
    b.backup_start_date AS 'Full',
    b.is_copy_only,
    c.backup_start_date AS 'Diff',
    d.backup_start_date AS 'Log',
    b.user_name
FROM master.sys.databases s
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset b
  ON s.name = b.database_name
  AND b.backup_start_date =
  (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date)as 'Full'
   FROM msdb..backupset
   WHERE database_name = b.database_name
   AND type = 'D') -- full database backups only, not log backups
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset c
  ON s.name = c.database_name
  AND c.backup_start_date =
  (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date)'Diff'
   FROM msdb..backupset
   WHERE database_name = c.database_name
   AND type = 'I')
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset d
  ON s.name = d.database_name
  AND d.backup_start_date =
  (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date)'Log'
   FROM msdb..backupset
   WHERE database_name = d.database_name
   AND type = 'L')
LEFT OUTER JOIN replicaInfo ri
  ON ri.serverName = @@SERVERNAME
  AND ri.databaseName  = s.name
WHERE s.name <> 'tempdb'
ORDER BY s.name;
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your input.
When executing I get a syntax error, will try to find what is not working in the new/added code

Comment: If you send me the error message, I can take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size.
It's your original query with a LOJ to a subquery that fetches that info for the local node and the AG the database belongs to.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(s.name,1,50) AS 'DATABASE Name', s.recovery_model_desc AS 'Recovery', s.state_desc AS 'Status', b.backup_start_date AS 'Full', b.is_copy_only, c.backup_start_date AS 'Diff', d.backup_start_date AS 'Log', b.user_name, ag.name, ag.role_desc
  FROM master.sys.databases s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset b
      ON s.name = b.database_name
      AND b.backup_start_date = (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) AS 'Full' FROM msdb.dbo.backupset WHERE database_name = b.database_name AND type = 'D') /* full database backups only, not log backups */
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset c
      ON s.name = c.database_name
      AND c.backup_start_date = (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) AS 'Diff' FROM msdb.dbo.backupset WHERE database_name = c.database_name AND type = 'I')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset d
      ON s.name = d.database_name
      AND d.backup_start_date = (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) AS 'Log' FROM msdb.dbo.backupset WHERE database_name = d.database_name AND type = 'L')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                     SELECT g.name, d.database_id, r.role_desc
                       FROM sys.availability_databases_cluster c
                         INNER JOIN sys.availability_groups g
                           ON c.group_id = g.group_id
                         INNER JOIN sys.databases d
                           ON c.group_database_id = d.group_database_id
                         INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states r
                           ON g.group_id = r.group_id
                           AND r.is_local = 1
                    ) ag
      ON s.database_id = ag.database_id
 WHERE s.name <> 'tempdb'
 ORDER BY s.name;
```

Example result set:

```
DATABASE Name               Recovery    Status  Full    is_copy_only        Diff    Log user_name   name            role_desc
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PSTest_Dev.REDCATED_Patrick FULL        ONLINE  NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL            NULL            NULL
PSTest_TestDB_Patrick_copy  FULL        ONLINE  NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL            NULL            NULL
DATABASE.REDCATED           FULL        ONLINE  NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL            Lab_NonDAG_AG   PRIMARY
DATABASE.REDACTED2          FULL        ONLINE  NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL            Lab1_AG         PRIMARY
```

Comment: Hello Patrick, Thank you for your input.  Your changes work great at pulling the AG status info, but unfortunately any instances not in an AG are no longer being pulled.  I also tried several methods of pulling the DB last backup and AG info and handed up with a much shorter list then with your query.

Comment: Hey @adriano, That's really strange. 
When I run the exact code on a server which has databases in several AGs and databases which are not in an AG I get results for both. I'll add an example result set to the answer above

Comment: Hello again @Patrick
I reversed the elements on the ON clause (ON          sys.databases.database_id=sys.master_files.database_id  )

Comment: Hello again @Patrick
Your query was a GREAT input into what I was wanting to do.  here is what I did and it resolved pulling the non HA servers for me.

I reversed the elements on the ON clause (ON          sys.databases.database_id=sys.master_files.database_id  )

and voila' all works as I wanted it.

Comment: Now I have another question for you as you seemed to have had a very similar need as mine.  Do you know/have you tried to execute the query from PowerShell against a registered group of servers?  I've created a registered group and that's how I execute the query.  Now I'd like to execute it from PS and have the returned results stored as a CSV file so it can be imported into a spreadsheet application.  Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but I think registered servers only exist on the particular machine, and I don't now where they are stored.

You could, alternatively, just create an array/list containing your servers and have PowerShell iterate over it.

Comment: I thought so too.  My group uses "local" regsvr lists, so the query you helped me with works great at pulling all the backup info from msdb tables and helped me confirm that a (nameless) product acquired touting it could backup secodary replicas in a "synchronous" AG  was not updating the backup logs in the secondary; As per MS design the secondary is locked to keep in sync with primary, so a fall would have to be performed before the log backup could be done and properly recorded.

Comment: Ultimately was hoping to automate the pull, from PS and output to comma delimited file for provision.  
Guess I'll have to export the XML read into an PS array and pass to the query via sqlcmd to generate what I want....perhaps easier said then done.
Either way, my sincere thanks for your valuable input